# traefik start error; Near line 183

Tags: traefik

Near line 183 (last key parsed 'frontends.frontend-hunter-dockercompose-backend.routes.service-backend'): expected a top-level item to end with a newline, comment, or EOF, but got 'H' instead

what does this mean? Any suggestion?

```
INFO[2017-08-04T18:26:27+08:00] Traefik version v1.3.5 built on 2017-08-01_03:55:31PM 
INFO[2017-08-04T18:26:27+08:00] Using TOML configuration file /var/data/app/traefik/traefik.toml 
DEBU[2017-08-04T18:26:27+08:00] Global configuration loaded {"GraceTimeOut":10000000000,"Debug":true,"CheckNewVersion":true,"AccessLogsFile":"","TraefikLogsFile":"","LogLevel":"DEBUG","EntryPoints":{"http":{"Network":"","Address":":80","TLS":null,"Redirect":null,"Auth":null,"Compress":false}},"Cluster":null,"Constraints":[],"ACME":null,"DefaultEntryPoints":["http"],"ProvidersThrottleDuration":2000000000,"MaxIdleConnsPerHost":200,"IdleTimeout":180000000000,"InsecureSkipVerify":false,"Retry":null,"HealthCheck":{"Interval":30000000000},"Docker":{"Watch":true,"Filename":"","Constraints":null,"Endpoint":"unix:///var/run/docker.sock","Domain":"docker.localhost","TLS":null,"ExposedByDefault":true,"UseBindPortIP":true,"SwarmMode":false},"File":null,"Web":{"Address":":8080","CertFile":"","KeyFile":"","ReadOnly":false,"Statistics":null,"Metrics":null,"Path":"","Auth":null},"Marathon":null,"Consul":null,"ConsulCatalog":null,"Etcd":null,"Zookeeper":null,"Boltdb":null,"Kubernetes":null,"Mesos":null,"Eureka":null,"ECS":null,"Rancher":null,"DynamoDB":null} 
INFO[2017-08-04T18:26:27+08:00] Preparing server http &{Network: Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> Compress:false} 
INFO[2017-08-04T18:26:27+08:00] Starting provider *docker.Provider {"Watch":true,"Filename":"","Constraints":null,"Endpoint":"unix:///var/run/docker.sock","Domain":"docker.localhost","TLS":null,"ExposedByDefault":true,"UseBindPortIP":true,"SwarmMode":false} 
INFO[2017-08-04T18:26:27+08:00] Starting provider *server.WebProvider {"Address":":8080","CertFile":"","KeyFile":"","ReadOnly":false,"Statistics":null,"Metrics":null,"Path":"","Auth":null} 
INFO[2017-08-04T18:26:27+08:00] Starting server on :80                       
DEBU[2017-08-04T18:26:27+08:00] Provider connection established with docker 17.06.0-ce (API 1.30) 
ERRO[2017-08-04T18:26:27+08:00] Near line 183 (last key parsed 'frontends.frontend-hunter-dockercompose-backend.routes.service-backend'): expected a top-level item to end with a newline, comment, or EOF, but got 'H' instead 
DEBU[2017-08-04T18:26:27+08:00] Configuration received from provider docker: null 
INFO[2017-08-04T18:26:27+08:00] Skipping empty Configuration for provider docker
```

Comment: version : v1.3.5

Comment: Could you please share your TOML and any other configurations you may use (such as a modified provider template)?

If you use labels, please share those too.